# Sync process during Async Process

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, async-await

I am using ASP.NET MVC Razor.

In my solution I used a controller with only one Action method. Layout has Left Navigation, Top part and Footer. Html part for these three are placed in the Partial Views and I am calling the partial views in layout like below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    @{Html.RenderPartial("HeaderScripts");}
</head>
<body class="nav-md">

    @{Html.RenderPartial("LeftSideNavigations");}
    @{Html.RenderPartial("TopView");}

    <div class="right_col" role="main">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    @{Html.RenderPartial("FooterScripts");}
</body>
</html>
```

This is due to the reason that my action method is like below.

```
[AttributeRouting.Web.Mvc.Route("All-Categories")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Categories()
{
    var list = await _category.CategoryList(null);
    return View(list.Value);
}
```

Here is the problem is...the results are coming using async, so I can't even call the action method for Partial Views in the layout like below.

```
@{
    Html.RenderAction("ActionName");
}
```

As I have to write some login in the action methods. I know we can't call it call this: `Html.RenderAction("ActionName")`  in VS 2013 as the Framework will never allow this.

> Question : Is there any way to to call the partial views except using
>   JQuery on DOM ready ?

Answer (score 0):

Async actions in `Controller`, from client perspective, are equal to non-async.

Marking Action with async only allows to free thread back to ThreadPool while requesting DB.

If you want to populate your parts asynchronously then you will need to use AJAX.
There are some interesting methods, if you are interested, like [this](http://blog.michaelckennedy.net/2012/11/13/improve-perceived-performance-of-asp-net-mvc-websites-with-async-partialviews/).